# Unexpected end of JSON input error but it appears the method has already been ran?

Tags: javascript, json, request

I'm using the etherscan API to return logs of some events. I think I'm parsing the json in a very conventional manner but it's throwing an error saying unexpected end of JSON

```js
function getEventHistory() {
    const topic0 = web3.utils.keccak256(config.event_string);
    document.getElementById("topic0").innerHTML = topic0;
    const qry = ("https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=logs&action=getLogs"+
                    "&fromBlock="+10338000+
                    "&toBlock="+"latest"+
                    "&address="+config.address+
                    "&topic0="+topic0+
                    "&apikey="+config.ether_api);
    console.log(qry)
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest()
    request.open("GET", qry);
    request.send();
    request.onreadystatechange=(e)=>{
        // document.getElementById("rLogsResp").innerHTML = request.responseText;
        parseResponse(request.responseText);
    }
}

function parseResponse(jsonString) {
    console.log("Converting string to jsonString: "+jsonString);
    const jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString)
    console.log("Full Response: "+jsonObj);

    var logs = []
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.result.length; i++) {
        console.log("Element Number: "+i);
        var event = jsonObj.result[i];
        console.log("Index: "+event);
        const parsedEvent = new Event(event);
        logs.push(parsedEvent)
        console.log(parsedEvent);
    }
}

class Event {
    constructor(event) {;
        console.log("Parse address: "+event.address);
        this.address = web3.utils.toAscii(event.address);
        console.log("Parse topics: "+event.topics);
        this.topics = [web3.utils.toAscii(event.topics[0]), web3.utils.toAscii(event.topics[1]), web3.utils.toAscii(event.topics[2])];
        console.log("Parse data: "+event.data);
        this.data = web3.utils.toAscii(event.data);
        console.log("Parse blockNumber: "+event.blockNumber);
        this.blockNumber = web3.utils.toAscii(event.blockNumber);
        console.log("Parse timeStamp: "+event.timeStamp);
        this.timeStamp = web3.utils.toAscii(event.timeStamp);
        console.log("Pares gasPrice: "+event.gasPrice);
        this.gasPrice = web3.utils.toAscii(event.gasPrice);
        console.log("Parse gasUsed: "+event.gasUsed);
        this.gasUsed = web3.utils.toAscii(event.gasUsed);
        console.log("Parse logIndex: "+event.logIndex);
        this.logIndex = web3.utils.toAscii(event.logIndex);
        console.log("Parse transactionHash: "+event.transactionHash);
        this.transactionHash = web3.utils.toAscii(event.transactionHash);
        console.log("Parse transactionIndex: "+event.transactionIndex)
        this.transactionIndex = web3.utils.toAscii(event.transactionIndex);
    }
}
```

I'm very new to JS but it seems like `onreadystatechange` is being called more than once because the error appears on `const jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString)` but then I get the logs from the for loop just below that.

Any ideas on what's wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct. `onreadystatechange` does get called multiple times.

The docs describe when they are called, and you can use the `readyState` property to find out what state the XHR currently is in:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange